# Cannot resolve module jquery.matchHeight-min when installing patternfly in local?

Tags: node.js, webpack, patternfly

Tried to install patternfly demo app from [github](https://github.com/patternfly/patternfly-demo-app) . These are the steps that i had followed for this :

1. npm install webpack
2. npm i
3. npm start

After running npm start i got response like this

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\Patternfly\patternfly>npm start

> patternfly-demo-app@1.0.0 start C:\Program Files\nodejs\Patternfly\patternfly
> npm run build:dev && node server/app.js


> patternfly-demo-app@1.0.0 build:dev C:\Program Files\nodejs\Patternfly\pattern
fly
> webpack --config build/webpack.config.js

[16:14:07] [write-file-webpack-plugin] options { exitOnErrors: true,
  force: false,
  log: true,
  test: null,
  useHashIndex: true }
[16:14:10] [write-file-webpack-plugin] compiler.outputFileSystem is "NodeOutputF
ileSystem".
Hash: 49a2d00b52f445fabc01
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 3602ms
    + 35 hidden modules

ERROR in ./src/js/main.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'jquery-match-height/jquery.match
Height-min' in C:\Program Files\nodejs\Patternfly\patternfly\src\js
 @ ./src/js/main.js 46:0-53
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
        + 4 hidden modules
[16:14:11] [write-file-webpack-plugin] options { exitOnErrors: true,
  force: false,
  log: true,
  test: null,
  useHashIndex: true }
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 ------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://xxx
 ------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://xxxx
 ------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: dist
[Browsersync] Watching files...
[16:14:16] [write-file-webpack-plugin] compiler.outputFileSystem is "MemoryFileS
ystem".
[16:14:16] [write-file-webpack-plugin] compiler.options.devServer.outputPath is
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\Patternfly\patternfly\dist".
webpack built 49a2d00b52f445fabc01 in 4687ms
Hash: 49a2d00b52f445fabc01
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 4687ms
               Asset      Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
      main.bundle.js   1.59 MB       0       main
    charts.bundle.js    371 kB       1       charts
    custom.bundle.js   22.5 kB       2       custom
          custom.css  38 bytes       2       custom
  main.bundle.js.map   1.94 MB       0       main
charts.bundle.js.map    441 kB       1       charts
custom.bundle.js.map   24.1 kB       2       custom
      custom.css.map  87 bytes       2       custom
chunk    {0} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 1.52 MB [rendered]
    [0] ./src/js/main.js 1.74 kB {0} [built] [1 error]
    [1] external "$" 42 bytes {0} [not cacheable]
    [2] ./~/script-loader/addScript.js 642 bytes {0} {1} [built]
    [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 251 bytes {0} [built]
    [4] ./~/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js 34.2 kB {0}
 [built]
    [5] ./~/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js 31.7 kB {0} [built]

    [6] ./~/bootstrap-touchspin/dist/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.min.js 9.34 kB {
0} [built]
    [7] ./~/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js 37 kB {0} [built]
    [8] ./~/datatables.net-colreorder/js/dataTables.colReorder.js 36 kB {0} [bui
lt]
    [9] ./~/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js 448 kB {0} [built]
   [10] ./~/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js 448 kB {0} [built]
   [11] ./~/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js 82.4 kB {0} [built]
   [12] ./~/drmonty-datatables-colvis/js/dataTables.colVis.js 27 kB {0} [built]
   [13] ./~/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.
min.js 36.8 kB {0} [built]
   [14] ./~/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/~/moment/moment.js 96.4 kB {0} [bu
ilt]
   [16] ./~/google-code-prettify/bin/prettify.min.js 14.6 kB {0} [built]
   [17] ./~/moment/min/moment.min.js 58.7 kB {0} [built]
   [18] ./~/patternfly-bootstrap-combobox/js/bootstrap-combobox.js 13.3 kB {0} [
built]
   [19] ./~/patternfly-bootstrap-treeview/dist/bootstrap-treeview.min.js 26.2 kB
 {0} [built]
   [20] ./~/patternfly/dist/js/patternfly.min.js 33.2 kB {0} [built]
   [23] ./~/raw-loader!./~/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js 86.5 kB {0} [built]
   [26] ./~/script-loader!./~/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js 440 bytes {0} [built]
   [27] (webpack)/buildin/amd-options.js 43 bytes {0} [built]
chunk    {1} charts.bundle.js, charts.bundle.js.map (charts) 349 kB [rendered]
    [0] ./src/js/charts.js 100 bytes {1} [built]
    [2] ./~/script-loader/addScript.js 642 bytes {0} {1} [built]
   [21] ./~/raw-loader!./~/c3/c3.min.js 194 kB {1} [built]
   [22] ./~/raw-loader!./~/d3/d3.min.js 154 kB {1} [built]
   [24] ./~/script-loader!./~/c3/c3.min.js 413 bytes {1} [built]
   [25] ./~/script-loader!./~/d3/d3.min.js 413 bytes {1} [built]
chunk    {2} custom.bundle.js, custom.css, custom.bundle.js.map, custom.css.map
(custom) 112 bytes [rendered]
    [0] ./src/js/custom.js 71 bytes {2} [built]
   [15] ./src/less/custom.less 41 bytes {2} [built]

ERROR in ./src/js/main.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'jquery-match-height/jquery.match
Height-min' in C:\Program Files\nodejs\Patternfly\patternfly\src\js
 @ ./src/js/main.js 46:0-53
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
    chunk    {0} extract-text-webpack-plugin-output-filename 1.76 kB [rendered]
        [0] ./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./~/autoprefixer-loader!./~/less-loader!./s
rc/less/custom.less 257 bytes {0} [built]
        [1] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 1.51 kB {0} [built]
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

The error is

```
ERROR in ./src/js/main.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'jquery-match-height/jquery.match
Height-min' in C:\Program Files\nodejs\Patternfly\patternfly\src\js
 @ ./src/js/main.js 46:0-53
```

But it is automatically opening `localhost:3000` in web browser. I can see the `jquery-match-height` module in node_modules but didn't find `jquery.matchHeight-min`in the module.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's just a typo in `./src/js/main.js`  where we need change the path of

`//MatchHeight - Used to make sure dashboard cards are the same height
require('jquery-match-height/jquery.matchHeight-min');`

TO

`require('jquery-match-height/dist/jquery.matchHeight-min');`